# How to subscribe to SSRS Report (SQL Server 2016)?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have installed SQL Server 2016 and have successfully published a report and now I want to create a subscription for the report. However, there is no subscription tab within the Web Portal, and there is not a Subscribe option on the drop down menu of the report.

I have made myself an admin and have ran the browser in admin mode. Is there a setting I'm missing to make subscriptions available?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must have access to the report. Before you can subscribe to a report, you must have permission to view it.

For Native mode report servers, the following role assignments affect subscriptions:

- The "Manage individual subscriptions" task allows users to create, modify, and delete subscriptions for a specific report. In the predefined roles, this task is part of Browser and Report Builder roles. Role assignments that include this task allow a user to manage only those subscriptions that he or she creates.
- The "Manage all subscriptions" task allows users to access and modify all subscriptions. This task is required to create data-driven subscriptions. In predefined roles, only the Content Manager role includes this task.